# Transformation and dimension

Tags: linear-transformations

This question rises from

> For a linear transformation $T \colon V \to W$,
>   When $\dim V = m$ and $\dim W = n$ then $T$ is invertible iff $m$ equals $n$.

, which is false.

---

When I asked about it in previous question, I was told its counter example would be
'a matrix which maps every element in $\mathbb{R}^m$ to zero vector ($\in \mathbb{R}^m$)' .

For me, it does not make sense.
V is domain, W is range(or image) and codomain would be entire $\mathbb{R}^m$ space.
and I've known that dimension of vector space depends on the number of linearly independent basis.

In this example, W is zero vector so it has zero basis *(Is it correct?)* thus dimW is 0 *(?)*.

So how can it be counter example?

Comment: The notation $T : V \to W$ means that $V$ is the domain and $W$ is the codomain. The image is usually denoted $T(V)$, and is a subspace of $W$ but not necessarily all of $W$. In the case of the zero map, the image $T(V)$ is $\{0\}$, which has dimension zero.

Comment: Thanks. I have been confused about it for a long time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case $\mathcal T$ is clearly not invertible, since it is not injective, i.e. "if $\mathcal Tv_1 = \mathcal Tv_2$ then $v_1=v_2$" does not hold. Indeed $v_1,v_2$ could be any pair of vectors in $V$. Invertible mappings are injective at least.

Also, $W$ is the **codomain** instead of the range.

Comment: Thanks. I was confusing W for image. Seeing W as codomain is yet strange to me. Is it just about definition?

Comment: Yes. $\mathcal T\colon V \to W$ means $\mathcal Tv \in W$, but not every $w \in W$ is in form of $\mathcal Tv$ for some $v \in V$. Maybe check the definition of "linear mapping" or "linear transformation" in any Linear Algebra textbook.